# Ruby on Rails Postgres Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm working o a Ruby on Rails application using PostgreSQL on Xubuntu (Xfce Desktop Environment). I downloaded postgresql using Linuxbrew

My database.yml looks like:

```
development:
  adapter:  postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: rado_dev_bouldin
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  pool:     5
  username: bouldin.15
```

First I was getting the issue that a server was already running and to check the `/tmp/pids/server.pid` file, I did that and killed the process using `kill -9 1420`

I ran `server s` again get the following outut:

```
$ rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.1.12 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.6.4 codename Gob Bluth)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

So it looks like it works, but once I actually open `http://localhost:3000/` I get the following output

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-03 14:07:55 -0500

PG::ConnectionBad - could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
:
  activerecord (4.1.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.1.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `new'
  activerecord (4.1.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
  activerecord (4.1.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.1.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
  activerecord (4.1.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
   () home/bouldin.15/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.1.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
  activerecord (4.1.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
   () home/bouldin.15/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.1.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.1.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.12) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.12) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.1.12) lib/active_record/migration.rb:388:in `check_pending!'
  activerecord (4.1.12) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  railties (4.1.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.12) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.12) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.12) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.12) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  railties (4.1.12) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.12) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.15.1.316) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  thin (1.6.4) lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.6.4) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
  thin (1.6.4) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.6.4) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
  thin (1.6.4) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.2.0.1) lib/eventmachine.rb:194:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (1.2.0.1) lib/eventmachine.rb:194:in `run'
  thin (1.6.4) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
  thin (1.6.4) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
  railties (4.1.12) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
  railties (4.1.12) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
  railties (4.1.12) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
  railties (4.1.12) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
  railties (4.1.12) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
  railties (4.1.12) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
   () home/bouldin.15/Psychology/RADO/bin/rails:8:in `require'
   () home/bouldin.15/Psychology/RADO/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
  spring (1.7.1) lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
  spring (1.7.1) lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
  spring (1.7.1) lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
  spring (1.7.1) lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
  spring (1.7.1) bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
  spring (1.7.1) lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
  spring (1.7.1) lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
   () home/bouldin.15/Psychology/RADO/bin/spring:16:in `require'
   () home/bouldin.15/Psychology/RADO/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
   () rails:3:in `load'
   () rails:3:in `<main>'



Started POST "/__better_errors/b6383117352c5f7e/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-03 14:07:55 -0500
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: You fix it by making sure you have postgres running and that you have the correct settings in `/config/db.yml`

Answer (score 1):

Resolved...

I tried to start the PostgreSQL database by using the `postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data` command. I got an error that my postgres data didn't exist and used the command `initdb PGDATA` to create it. Then I used `pg_ctl -D PGDATA -l logfile start` to start the server. Then I had to recreate my database so I ran `$bin\rake db:create db:migrate`